# Can a player take a card from the researcher on their turn if they have the co-worker relationship but are not in the same city?

Tags: pandemic-legacy-season-1

It is the generalist turn. Can she take a card from the researcher if they have the co worker relation?

Answer (score 2):

**Yes.**

Co-worker allows players to Share Knowledge at a distance under specific conditions. When the researcher is the one passing the card, it overrides that condition, whether it's the researcher or another character initiating the action.